# How to get IE 11 to stop asking if i want to block alerts

Tags: internet-explorer

I still want to allow alerts, the issue is that my automation software will not work when the alert changes. For example, I click save, and alert pops up saying, you must enter your email. I click OK. I then enter email, and click save, then i get an alert saying "You must enter your password". Since this happens so fast in automation the 2nd alert has an extra checkbox asking if i want to block IE from sending these alerts. This new alert is different enough that my automation software see's it as a different window, so it breaks the code.

Does anyone know if it is possible to stop these prompts from asking if i want to stop the alerts? or hell, always ask.

Comment: Can you please try to post the snapshot of the popup shown by the IE browser? Your description is not giving a proper idea about which exact popup is shown. It can help us to find whether there is any possible way to stop it or not. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: its an alert. a basic alert.

Comment: There are almost certain to be better ways of achieving what you want to do without using `alert()`. It's a very very old-school way of doing things. When was the last time you came accross a site that had alert boxes for field validation?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your web page is generating multiple alerts. So after the first alert, the browser shows a checkbox for **Don't let this page create more messages**.

[image]

This is where your automation software broke because it is not able to identify the alert().

To prevent IE for showing **Don't let this page create more messages** checkbox you need to add your site to the **Trusted site** list.

you can go to **Tools-> Internet options-> Security tab-> Trusted sites-> Sites** and add your site to the list.

[image]

Then after it will not show this checkbox in an alert().

Output:

[image]